how to get the location of the backup too? you can use multiple columns pivoting or any other way!
I got this great query that shows the latest backup for each existing database.
SELECT
    M.name,
    [Recovery Model] = 
        M.recovery_model_desc,
    [State] = 
        M.state_desc,
    [Last Full Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.D, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [Last Differential Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.I, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [Last log Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.L, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        db.name,
        db.state_desc,
        db.recovery_model_desc,
        a.type,
        a.backup_finish_date
    FROM master.sys.databases AS db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
      ON a.database_name = db.name
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(backup_finish_date)
    FOR type IN
    (
        D,
        I,
        L
    )
) AS M --ostRecentBackup
WHERE name NOT IN
(
    N'master',
    N'msdb',
    N'model',
    N'tempdb'
);

I noticed it uses pivoting - what if I had to add the location too? that would be multiple columns.
Either by pivoting using multiple columns, or unpivoting, how could I add the location of each backup type to the above query?
basically where is the latest full backup, where is the latest diff and the latest log (if any).
this is the script I use to see the location of the backup:
SELECT   
   CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.TYPE,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size * 1.024 /1024/1024 as [Backup size in MB],
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,   
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
           ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
--WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = 'PivCRM_Prod_Online_ED'
--AND TYPE = 'D'  -- L D and I
ORDER BY msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date DESC


the question is:
how would I add the location of the backup (each type) to the first query?

I have made several adjustments for it to work. I opted not to use the PIVOT syntax, instead utilizing CASE WHEN with GROUP BY clauses to pivot multiple columns.

Innermost Query: This retrieves information about backups (including date and location) for all user databases. It uses a ROW_NUMBER() function, partitioned by database name and backup type, to assign a unique row number to each backup entry, ordered by the backup finish date in descending order (so that the latest backup has rn=1).

Second Inner Query: Filters to retain only the latest backup per database and backup type by selecting rows with rn = 1.

Outer Query: Uses CASE WHEN statements to pivot the data, allowing multiple columns (such as finish date, and location) per backup type to be displayed for each database row.


-- The outer query to pivot using CASE WHEN
SELECT name,
    [Recovery Model] = recovery_model_desc,
    [State] = state_desc,
    FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'D' THEN backup_finish_date END), '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm') AS [Last Full Backup],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'D' THEN physical_device_name END) AS [Last Full Backup Physical Location],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'D' THEN logical_device_name END) AS [Last Full Backup Logical Location],
    FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'L' THEN backup_finish_date END), '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm') AS [Last Log Backup],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'L' THEN physical_device_name END) AS [Last Log Backup Physical Location],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'L' THEN logical_device_name END) AS [Last Log Backup Logical Location],
    FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'I' THEN backup_finish_date END), '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm') AS [Last Differential Backup],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'I' THEN physical_device_name END) AS [Last Differential Physical Backup Location],
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'I' THEN logical_device_name END) AS [Last Differential Logical Backup Location]
FROM
(
    -- The second inner select to select the latest backup for each database type of each db 
    SELECT Name,
           recovery_model_desc,
           state_desc,
           type,
           backup_finish_date,
           physical_device_name,
           logical_device_name
    FROM
    (
        -- The first inner select to select all backup details
        SELECT
            db.Name,
            db.recovery_model_desc,
            db.state_desc,
            a.type,
            a.backup_finish_date,
            b.physical_device_name,
            b.logical_device_name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY db.Name, a.type ORDER BY a.backup_finish_date DESC) rn
        FROM master.sys.databases AS db
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
            ON a.database_name = db.name
        LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily b
            ON a.media_set_id = b.media_set_id
        WHERE db.Name NOT IN
        (
            N'master',
            N'msdb',
            N'model',
            N'tempdb'
        ) 
    ) Backups
    WHERE rn = 1
) LatestBackups
GROUP BY name
    , recovery_model_desc
    , state_desc
ORDER BY name

The result table looks like this:

you are amazing. the only thing I changed is the format parameter: ,FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'D' THEN backup_finish_date END), '19000101'), 'dddd, dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt') AS [Last Full Backup] but the script is perfect for what it does, thanks a lot
